# Remove previous drop down selection from future drop down options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that presents you with an option to insert a row. The row has a drop down menu with around 10 values to choose from. When I click the insert button to insert another row I need the new drop down that is generated to NOT have the previous row's selected value in the options. Basically it's like a bunch of cascading drop downs. The new drop down will not have the previous drop down's selected option.

Basically my question is how could/should I go about implementing this with JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: You should always provide some code explaining what did you try or replicating the situation

Comment: There's no code to show, I need an idea on how to approach this.

Comment: This question is too broad. First of all, you must TRY something. SO is not the forum, you cannot expect to SO coders do everything for you. Write some code, and SO will help you to resolve issues or bugs. If you need an opinion or advice, ask on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23598/jquery

Comment: Wondering whether the answer helped..!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your code to give a good answer, but you can remove an option like this...

```
$("#yourdropdownlistid option[value='thevalueofthetargetoption']").remove();
```

You might try changeing the option value of the selected item to 'remove' on change, then you can target all of the 'remove' option values.

```
$("#yourdropdownlistid option[value='thevalueofthetargetoption']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

you can see it running here...
http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1420/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
 <button>add</button>
 <div class='row'>
    <select>
        <option>hi</option>
        <option>hello</option>
        <option>how</option>
        <option>are</option>
        <option>you</option>
    </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can do it as follows:

```
$('button').click(function () {
 var clone= $('.row').last().clone();
 clone.find('option:selected').remove();
 if($(clone).find('option').length>0)
  $('#container').append(clone);
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Juzz8/)